# Determine radius in shell method given a graph of the function when revolving around line x=6

Tags: calculus

[image: I.]

II. [image]

[image]

For this problem, the radius of the shell from x= 0 to a is 6-x. Why not use 6+x?

Comment: drawing a picture may help, but I'm to sure how to draw the cylinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we want is the distance to the axis of rotation. If $x=0$ then $6-x=6$ and $6+x=6$. However, if $x=\dfrac{a}{2}$ then $6-x=6-\dfrac{a}{2}$ which is the correct distance and $6+x=6+\dfrac{a}{2}$ which is not the correct distance form $6$ to $\dfrac{a}{2}$.